# Magento 2 - How to get new data after first data migration?

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration, delta-migration

I created a fresh magento 2.3.5-p1 shop and migrated the data from an M1 store by using the `php bin/magento migrate:data` command.

Now one week later new data was added to the M1 shop (two new CMS sites: cat, dog) and some old sites were removed from M2 (donkey, horse).

Can I trigger a migration so that the changes from M1 are getting transfered to M2?

And will this load the deleted CMS sites (donkey, horse) into M2 again?

---

**Output of**:

```
php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.4.4/config.xml
```

---

```
[company@company]$ php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.4.4/config.xml

[2020-07-15 07:43:37][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
...................................................................................................................................
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity Source: 2250 Destination: 50
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity_int Source: 11767 Destination: 133
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity_varchar Source: 3556 Destination: 17
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity Source: 2643 Destination: 62
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity_datetime Source: 132 Destination: 1
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity_varchar Source: 252 Destination: 2
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2020-07-15 07:43:37][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
...................................................................................................................................
[2020-07-15 07:43:41][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity Source: 56 Destination: 55
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_datetime Source: 110 Destination: 94
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_decimal Source: 55 Destination: 47
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_int Source: 333 Destination: 334
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_text Source: 277 Destination: 258
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_varchar Source: 441 Destination: 434
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_compare_item Source: 2 Destination: 0
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity Source: 6029 Destination: 5929
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_datetime Source: 27986 Destination: 27511
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal Source: 14871 Destination: 14548
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_int Source: 36933 Destination: 36383
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery Source: 735 Destination: 734
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value Source: 735 Destination: 734
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_text Source: 22765 Destination: 22377
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_varchar Source: 78457 Destination: 77130
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link Source: 953 Destination: 594
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link_attribute_int Source: 944 Destination: 585
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option Source: 612 Destination: 584
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_price Source: 290 Destination: 280
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_title Source: 612 Destination: 584
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_price Source: 1659 Destination: 1597
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_title Source: 1659 Destination: 1597
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_value Source: 1659 Destination: 1597
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_relation Source: 5583 Destination: 5485
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute Source: 143 Destination: 139
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute_label Source: 143 Destination: 139
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_link Source: 5167 Destination: 5069
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_website Source: 6027 Destination: 5927
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock_item Source: 6029 Destination: 5929
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: newsletter_subscriber Source: 2997 Destination: 1806
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_compared_product_index Source: 1 Destination: 0
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event Source: 1152406 Destination: 1105350
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_tax Source: 13470 Destination: 12764
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_tax_item Source: 49810 Destination: 47090
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist Source: 847 Destination: 5
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2020-07-15 07:43:44][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
...................................................................................................................................
[2020-07-15 07:43:46][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_visitor Source: 3037874 Destination: 2959584
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
....................................................
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_grid Source: 13457 Destination: 12744
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
.
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Inventory Step]: started
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Inventory Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Inventory Step]: Migration completed successfully
[2020-07-15 07:43:52][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Inventory Step]: Automatic restart in 5 sec. Use CTRL-C to abort^C
```

Comment: it should work. `bin/magento migrate:delta <path_of_config_xml_file> -vvv`

Comment: @yvzyldrm, I tried it, but the new CMS Sites from M1 are not existing in M2 after it.

Comment: I am sorry. CMS content doesn't migrate. It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento wrote;
[Magento Delta Migration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html)

> All other new or updated entities entered through the Admin panel, such as attributes or CMS pages, are not included in the incremental migration and will not be migrated.

[Magento Migration Plan](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-plan.html#step-4-start-your-migration)

If migration has started, nothing should be entered from the admin panel.

Maybe you can move the database manually for only cms tables.

Comment: *"If migration has started, nothing should be entered from the admin panel."*
Then how should I setup magento 2 before going live, install new extensions and configure everything???

Comment: You must have everything ready before migration. Because after migration, only shopping can be from the m1 site. Delta migration is for this. You should do staging your tests at first. When it's ready, you can merge your settings into two databases. for example; core_config_data table. well, we do that.

Comment: Sorry, but where in the documentation did you read about that we are not allowed to make changes in our M2 shop after data migration?? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: No, you can make changes m2 site. But you can't make changes m1 site except for shopping. I think migration is a one time process. For example, it should end in one day. Details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-plan.html#step-6-update-incremental-data

Comment: Ok, so I first have to migrate settings and data from M1 and stop making any changes in M1, then install all new M2 extensions and configure them and test everything. So I am not allowed to make any changes during this time, which can be a week. Damn...

Answer (score 0):

Your new data coming to M1 store after migration is named Data Changes and can be migrated using Magento migration tool. Refer to this document for details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html.

Comment: I already tried the delta migration, but it does not transfer the new cms sites (cat, dog) from M1 to M2